# Getting cookies in a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get a cookie specifically from a domain using this code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var ID;

function getCookies(domain, name) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        ID = cookie.value;
    });
}

getCookies("http://www.example.com", "id")
alert(ID);

</script>
```

The problem is that the alert always says undefined. However, if I change

```
ID = cookie.value;
```

to

```
alert(cookie.value);
```

it works properly. How do I save the value to use later?

Update: It appears that if I call alert(ID) from the chrome console after the script runs, it works. How can I set my code to wait until chrome.cookies.get finishes running?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Almost all Chrome API calls are asynchronous, so you need to use callbacks to run code in order:

```
function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        if(callback) {
            callback(cookie.value);
        }
    });
}

//usage:
getCookies("http://www.example.com", "id", function(id) {
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: How can I modify it to save it as a variable? When i tried ID = id instead of alert(id), i still got undefined.

Comment: @DazSlayer All your code that relies on asynchronous calls should be rewritten using callbacks. So if you need this ID in some other place you need to put that code inside a callback as well. Code here is not executed line by line. If you worked with ajax it is the same story, just think if you are sending ajax requests to chrome api.

Comment: note that you should add **"manifest_version": 2** into **manifest.json**

Comment: where must I call getCookie (also where do i place that code)? in my background.js or my content.js? or can I put it in another script? i have an app.html which opens up like "chrome-extension://efmbliijihpahlhiamhmmfkbjkecofec/app.html"

Answer (score 5):

Any code that depends on the result of the call to chrome.cookies.get() will have to be invoked from within the callback. In your example, just wait for the callback to fire before you show the alert:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    var ID;

    function getCookies(domain, name) 
    {
        chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
            ID = cookie.value;
            showId();
        });
    }

    function showId() {
        alert(ID);
    }

    getCookies("http://www.example.com", "id")        

</script>
```

Comment: where must I call getCookie (also where do i place that code)? in my background.js or my content.js? or can I put it in another script? i have an app.html which opens up like "chrome-extension://efmbliijihpahlhiamhmmfkbjkecofec/app.html"

Answer (score 1):

To get all cookies under a domain:

```
 const r = await chrome.cookies.getAll({ domain: domain }) //domain: stackoverflow.com
```

This script can be run from popup and background service worker but not a content script.

Comment: This only works in manifest v3