# Chrome extension: "No permission for cookies at url"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I try to get Cookies from a special Website.

Manifest permissions:

```
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"*//*free-way.me",
"storage",
 "cookies"
],
```

And this is my popup.js:

```
function getCookies(domain, name) 
{
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        return cookie.value;

    });
}

var uid = getCookies("http://.free-way.me", "uid")     
var upw = getCookies("http://.free-way.me", "upw")     

document.getElementById("user").value = uid;
document.getElementById("pw").value = upw;
```

..but it's just telling me, that I'd no permissions:

```
cookies.get: No host permissions for cookies at url: "http://.free-way.me/".
at getCookies (chrome-extension://[...]/popup.js:19:24)
at chrome-extension://[...]/popup.js:25:13
```

Can you tell me please my mistake I made?...It drives me cracy. Thank you!

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [match pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) is malformed. You're missing a period after the asterisk in the host name:

```
"*//*.free-way.me"
```

If the *host* identifier has a `*`, it must either:

- be the entire *host* identifier, or
- be the first character of the *host* identifier and be followed immediately by a period.

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives me the same error.. and btw, the domainname in the cookie is named ".free-way.me". Is my requested URL correct? Thanks mate!

Comment: @wernersbacher You also are misusing the asynchronous extension APIs. See the "Restructure code" section in [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/710446) for an overview of how to use asynchronous callback functions. (That shouldn't give you a cookie-error, but it will stop your code from working.)

Comment: @wernersbacher Have you tried removing the leading period and just asking for `free-way.me`? I've never used the cookies API myself, and the documentation is a bit sparse, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, I tried nearly every possibility, but it didn't work. Now I got a Callback Function, even if I don't really understand it. I used this one: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892176/getting-cookies-in-a-google-chrome-extension Thank you @apsillers

Comment: I forgot to say that it works fine now. Thank you for your help. Have a good night!

Comment: @wernersbacher  How did you fix the issue with the starting point? I cant delete them...

Comment: @Esteban Sorry, I don't know anymore, and I can't find the sources of this project anymore. :/

Answer (score 3):

some change have been taken place in Manifest version 3 about host permission.In MV3, you'll need to specify host permissions separately from other permissions:

```
// Manifest V2
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks",
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
],
"optional_permissions": [
  "*://*/*",
  "unlimitedStorage"
]

 // Manifest V3
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks"
],
"optional_permissions": [
  "unlimitedStorage"
],
"host_permissions": [
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
  "*://*/*"
],
```